# eigenvalue of symmetric matrix where some diagonal elements dominate

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A symmetric matrix $M$ has the following properties:

$$
M_{ii}\gg M_{ij}    ~~~~~~   i\neq j  ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{for}~  i>i_0~~~~~~
$$

and all the dominated diagonal elements are equal.

My question is:

Can some of the eigenvalues of $M$ be approximated by making all $M_{ij}=0$ for $i>i_0>j$ and $i<i_0<j$

Comment: You can certainly approximate the eigenvalues by the diagonal elements by the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).  It would not make sense to disregard the other entries on the diagonal.

Comment: I should add a condition that all dominated diagonal entries are equal.